# How to select path with the latest version number when using glob in Python?

Tags: python, glob

Here is code snippet:

```
glob.glob('C:\\intelFPGA\\*')
['C:\\intelFPGA\\17.1', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\18.0', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\18.1', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\20.0', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\9.2']
```

I need a method that will return the path string that has the latest version number which is 18.1 in this case. Is there a built in way to do this or am I limited to doing string manipulation to achieve this i.e a custom solution?

Comment: Isn't the latest `20.0`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the latest version in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996134/finding-the-latest-version-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path('C:\\intelFPGA')
latest = max(root.glob('*'), key=lambda p: float(p.name))
```

If you can have more parts than 2 in version, like major.minor.patch then this will not work. You can do this instead:

```py
root = Path('C:\\intelFPGA')
latest = max(root.glob('*'), key=lambda p: tuple(map(int, p.name.split('.'))))
```

Comment: Yes, `[-1]` sorry. and yes `max` is better.

Comment: The float approach doesn't work with minor versions > 9 because e.g. `1.12` is sorted before `1.9`. +1 For the other solution. If anyone is curious why this works: "because tuples are compared lexicographically" as described in the [sorting howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-decorate-sort-undecorate).

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

folders = ['C:\\intelFPGA\\17.1', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\18.0', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\18.1', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\20.0', 'C:\\intelFPGA\\9.2']


data = {}

for folder in folders:
    info = folder.split("\\")
    version = float(info[-1])
    data.update({version:folder})


s = SortedDict(data)
print(s)
```

your result will be:

```
SortedDict({9.2: 'C:\\intelFPGA\\9.2', 17.1: 'C:\\intelFPGA\\17.1', 18.0: 'C:\\intelFPGA\\18.0', 18.1: 'C:\\intelFPGA\\18.1', 20.0: 'C:\\intelFPGA\\20.0'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pathlib.Path.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with [packaging.version.parse()](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version/#packaging.version.parse):

```py
from packaging import version
from pathlib import Path 


def get_latest(folder):
    selected_path = None
    latest_version = version.parse('0')
    for item in Path(folder).glob('*'):
        if not item.is_dir():
            continue

        ver = version.parse(item.name)

        if isinstance(ver, version.LegacyVersion):
            continue # not PEP 440 compatible version

        if ver > latest_version:
            latest_version = ver
            selected_path = str(item)

    return selected_path

latest_path = get_latest(r'C:\intelFPGA')
```

#### Short explanation

- The `glob('*')` iterates over all content in the folder
- The `item.is_dir()` is needed to filter out everything which is not a directory
- The `isinstance(ver, version.LegacyVersion)` is needed since you may have a folder there that does not match your pattern (folder name that contains other characters than numbers and dots.)
- The `packaging.version` is needed for version comparison, since `version.parse('1.12') > version.parse('1.5')`, but `float('1.12') < float('1.5')`, and `"1.2.3"` is also a valid version name.

Comment: What if glob returns empty since no match was made? I guess we can just run a check before we enter the loop right?

Comment: Then the `get_latest()` will return `None`. You could handle this later by checking if the return value is `None` or a string pointing to the desired path.